# Did anyone know how to disable swipe gesture in ionic 4 pwa app (ios device)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

this is happen only in pwa app in ios.In the native ios application this working fine.

this is how i disabled swipe gesture in native app. => ion-router-outlet main [swipeGesture]="false"

[You can see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpyrQ.jpg)

**expected result** in ios =>`swipeGesture = false`
**actual result** in ios => `swipeGesture = true`

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
this.slides.lockSwipes(true); // this will disable the swipe in either ways
this.slides.lockSwipes(false); // this will enable the swipe in either ways
```

2.

```
<ion-slide class=“swiper-no-swiping”>
```